# Simplifying a logical compound statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need to simplify $(p \vee r) \wedge (\neg p \vee \neg r)$ (if possible and using the laws of logic)

I tried to substitue $s: (\neg p \vee r)$ but that made it even worse.

Can anyone suggest an alternate way to approach this problem? Not looking for a solution, but a hint on how I can make some progress.

Comment: Bump for morbid interest

Comment: Maybe if you make a truth table for the sentence, the answer will jump out. There are also syntactic arguments.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I forgot to mention that I would like to use the Laws of Logic to simplify the statement. I'll update my question!

Comment: Instead, try substituting $ s: p \lor r$ if you are not comfortable distributing from the right. After that you will need to make use of the commutativity of $\land$ to distribute from the left again.

Comment: Which laws of logic can you use?

Answer (score 1):

the answer is $r$. In fact using distribution law we have, $(p{\wedge{\sim}p)\vee}r=r{\vee}F=r$

Comment: Had a huge brain fart and realized I put in the wrong compound statement. I've updated the question now, thanks for your answer though.

Comment: I think the answer to the original OP question is not $r$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that by simple testing, you can tell what's going on.

If $p$ is true, the result is $r$.

If $p$ is false, the result is $r$.

So, the expression is equivalent to just plain old $r$.

This is a simple tactic that may help you simplify some expressions: just fix one variable and see what falls out, then do the same with the opposite value for the variable. You may be able to make an observation based on this experiment. If not, little is lost.

Comment: Had a huge brain fart and realized I put in the wrong compound statement. I've updated the question now, thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

**For the modified question:** If $p$ is true, $r$ must be false.

If $p$ is false, $r$ must be true.

So the formula is equivalent to "$p\iff\neg r$".